# Почему не включатся скрипты в файл с помощью gulp-deporder?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Подключаю в шапке в основном файле вот это:

```
/* require
foo/bar.js
*/
```

Если файлы в той же директории что и основной файл, работает нормально. Но если вложить их в подпапки то выходит ошибка:

```
script.js requires foo/bar.js which was not found
```

В настройках задачи, путь к файлам вот такой:

```
folder.src + 'js/**/*.js
```

В чем проблема?

Весь код задачи:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    var jsbuild = gulp.src(folder.src + 'js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(deporder())
        .pipe(concat('main.js'));

    if (devBuild) {
        return jsbuild
            .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.dev + 'js/'))
            .pipe(reload({
                stream: true
            }));
    }
    return jsbuild
        .pipe(gulp.dest(folder.dist + 'js/'));
});
```

Comment: Покажите всю настройку задачи

Comment: @VasiliyAlania Обновил вопрос.